# Using <select> on an update form

Tags: php, pdo

I have an edit form with two fields: name and category. The category field is stored in the database as a number. I would like to associate each number (3 in total) to a string in the edit form and display the category recorded in the database and then the other.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result->name; ?>">

<select name="categoria">
    <option value="<?php echo $result->category; ?>">books</option>
    <option value="2">cds</option>
    <option value="3">dvds</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there was a question there, but I think I know what you're trying to do. I don't know what your table structure is like, so this is just an example.

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_title ASC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $num = $row['category_number'];
    $val = $row['category_title'];

    echo '<option value="' . $num . '">' . $val . '</option>';
}
```

That will give you all of the options for your select element, set their value to the number from the database, and display the name of the category for the viewer.

EDIT:

Here's using the MySQLi class, which will save you some time. However, there's not much use in building a class for this particular function. It's so short.

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY category_name ASC");

while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
{
    $num = $row['category'];
    $val = $row['category_title'];

    echo '<option value="' . $num . '">' . $val . '</option>';
}
```

EDIT 2:

Just use the while() loop, rather than do...while(). It'd go like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY category_name ASC");

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $num = $row['category'];
    $val = $row['categoty_name'];

    echo '<option value="' . $num . '">' . $val . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Kacey, I have a table called products. Inside, there is a column called category. In this column I store numbers: 1 for books, cds and 2 for 3 for DVDs.
In select field on the edit form, I call the number and category must associate it with the name of the category.

Comment: Then you need to edit your products table, and include a second column called category_name, or something similar, and pull that information. Otherwise, you'll have to create an array with your names, and it's more work than it's worth. Then just update the table name in the SQL query, and the column names in the $row variables.

Comment: Kacey. I understand now. But how I write your code using PDO?

Comment: If you want to write a class for this particular function, just visit the PHP PDO page for more information. It's so small that you wouldn't really need a class for it, though.